# "Illegal instruction: 4" when running PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, pycharm, gevent

I can’t get Pycharm in my current project to run the debugger.

When I run the debugger, it just shows that the debug command exited:

```
    /Users/jeremie/.local/share/virtualenvs/proxi-server/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 52293 --file /Users/jeremie/Code/proxi-server/server.py

Process finished with exit code 132
```

I ran that command on my terminal to figure out the problem and it showed:

```
Illegal instruction: 4
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple at the end:

> I use Gevent in my project and the latest
>   version had a problem with the architecture of my computer.

### Uninstall Gevent

```
$ pip uninstall gevent
```

### Install the magic version

```
$ pip install gevent==1.1b5
```